# How to temporarily block the ability to click a menu item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, menu

I have a menu when I click on a specific element of which the activity opens, but the user can quickly click menu iten 2 times, which will lead to the opening of the activity 2 times. How can I block the ability to press a button after the first press?

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.create) {
            // start activity 
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I know about setEnabled, but when I return to enabled activity, it remains false, and it seems inconvenient to save MenuItem and return its state. Anyone have any ideas how to do this optimally?

Comment: create a flag and set it as `activity 1 loading` , for the second click the same method will be invoked, if the flag is set then don't start the activity, if you want to do this generic way you try `launchMode='singleTask'` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can also try `android:launchMode = "singleTop"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution to this problem. To do this, add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag to the Intent. Thanks to this, it will be impossible to create 2 activities.

```
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```